# determine default UISearchBar background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using a `UISearchBar` inside a `UIView` with a filter button next to the `UISearchBar`. I'd like to maintain the default `UISearchBar` background color and use it as background color for the filter button. How can I determine the background color and alpha value?

[image]

Comment: What about a `clearColor` for the button background?

Comment: the button is not a subview of UISearchBar. both are sibling views within a UIView having white background color.

Comment: I see. Is changing the backgroundColor of the UISearchBar to the one you are using right now for the UIButton an option?

Answer (score 0):

Using DigitalColorMeter application you can get the RGB color.

Comment: I've tried this way. you can see the result on the image. I suppose the background has some alpha value but the DigitalColorMeter does not give you the alpha component, only the resulting RGB values.